# Excel VBA - Convert string to range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that stores a range.address in a cell.
The value of that cell is IE: AQ43:BF44

How can I turn this string into a Range?

I have tried:

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim pRange As String
Dim projectRange As Range
    pRange = Project.Range ' Stored as "AQ43:BF44" in this case
    projectRange = Range(pRange)

    For Each Cell In projectRange
        If TargetCell = Cell Then
           'Do something
        End If
    Next Cell
```

This code reports run-time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

The main purpose of this function is to check if the targetCell(the cell I doubleclicked) is found within the stored range.address .

Comment: `pRange = projectRange.Value` and not `pRange = Project.Range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sup>The main purpose of this function is to check if the targetCell(the cell I doubleclicked*[sic]*) is found within the stored range.address</sup>

You are looking to see if the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) produces something that is within the range described by the text in a cell (e.g. `AQ43:BF44` ) and a cell you double-click (e.g. `Target` ).

```
Option Explicit    '<~~ see footnote

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim pRange As String
    pRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2
    'alternates
    'pRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value
    'pRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").text
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(pRange)) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = False
        MsgBox Target.Address(0, 0) & " is within " & pRange
    End If
End Sub
```

You are seeking to retrieve text from a cell; possibly text that is returned from a formula involving something like the [ADDRESS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89). For this you can use the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx), [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) or [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx). Strictly speaking, the .Value2 property is the fastest but it isn't going to make a lot of difference here.

It's a little unclear on where the text (e.g. `AQ43:BF44` ) resides. I've included parent worksheet as well as range definition that should be easy to edit.

A global solution could be achieved with the **ThisWorkbook**'s [Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.sheetbeforedoubleclick.aspx) event macro.

---

<sub>Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is widely considered 'best practice'.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Using intersect solved the problem flawlessly. Had no problem working your solution into my worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

Since a `Range` is an "object" in Excel, you need to use the `Set`-keyword when assigning values:

```
Set projectRange = Range(pRange)
```

You will, however, encounter an error if the value of `pRange`doesn't describe a valid `Range`.

Also, you might want to be a bit more specific when iterating over `For Each Cell In projectRange`. Depending on what you want to do, you could iterate over `projectRange.Cells`, `projectRange.Rows`, `projectRange.Columns`...